# Show that this RSA encryption iterated $10$ times does not encrypt $x$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Let's say we have an RSA key of modulus $n = 383\cdot563 = 215629$ and encryption exponent $e = 49$. Suppose our encryption $E(x)=(x^{49})^{10}$ where we are iterating $x^{e}$ ten times. I want to show that $E(x)=x$. It seems like I just need to show that the decryption key $d=10$. Usually, to find decryption keys, I've used the fact that

$$de\equiv 1 \mod (p-1)(q-1)$$

But since $490\equiv 64\mod {(383-1)(563-1)}$ It must not be true then, that for ***every*** RSA encryption and decryption exponents $e$ and $d$ that $de\equiv 1 \mod (p-1)(q-1)$, right? What's different about this case?

How do I prove that $E(x)=x$? That is, how do I show $x^{490}\equiv x\mod 215629$? What does this say about an eavesdropper that doesn't know the prime factors of $n$?

I'm told I can use the fact that

$7^{20} \equiv 1 \mod 191$ and $7^{20} \mod 281$ which does mean $49^{10} \equiv 1$ for those...

Comment: I just realized $191$ and $281$ divide $(p-1)(q-1)$ as well

Comment: @kelalaka I thought it worked for $x=3,4,5...$ but I must've been looking at something else.

Comment: @kelalaka The actual problem states "Suppose we let $E$ denote encryption with this public key, so $E(x) = x^{49}    (\mod 215629)$.  Show that
                                E^10(x) = x (where $E^k$ denotes $E$ iterated $k$ times)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let we have RSA encrypt $E(x) = x^{49}  \bmod 215629$ then the double RSA encrypt is
\begin{align}
E^2(x) &= (x^{49})^{49}  \bmod 215629\\
 &= \color{red}{x^{49\cdot49}}  \bmod 215629\\
 &= x^{49^2}  \bmod 215629\\
 &= x^{2401}  \bmod 215629\\
\end{align}

Now, if you encrypt 10 times than

\begin{align}
E^{10}(x) &= ((x^{49})^{{49}^{\cdots^{49}}} )  \bmod 215629\\
 &= x^{49^{10}}  \bmod 215629\\
 &= x^{79792266297612001}  \bmod 215629\\
\end{align}

From [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) we know that $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$

The $\varphi(383\cdot 563) = (383-1)\cdot (563-1)= 214684$

With a simple test $$79792266297612001 = 1 \bmod 214684$$

Comment: Thank you, I think I misunderstood the iteration part

Comment: [Serial exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Serial_exponentiation)